# Opening HDFS folder

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

Good day
I Have some questions about the following Command in Hadoop (as I am new to Linux/Ubuntu):

```
   bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/folder /user/hduser/folder
```

This copies the files from the local file system to HDFS; would it be possible to access the HDFS from Ubuntu's GUI? without using "-ls" in shell? like in, I want to open the folder where the HDFS files are located in...Would this be possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some options for 'mounting' HDFS in the local OS, see:

- http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/MountableHDFS

Comment: I see, So it is not like There is a folder I would access directly in Ubuntu and in there I would see the files residing in the HDFS  (Like Usr/Local/HDFS has the files in the HDFS) ?

Comment: It's a distributed file system, each node in the cluster has blocks which constitute a file, but no, you cannot just browse somewhere on the local disk to see the files